# Pig basic program error

Tags: apache-pig

I am getting the below error while running a pig script.[![
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KvMB.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KvMB.jpg)

Comment: Enter the error in rather than posting a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read Pig manual carefully

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/start.html

and observe that -x expects execution mode to be specified (either local or mapreduce). So the correct command would be

`pig -x local wordcount.pig`